# odd xorg hang when starting intellij

Tags: nvidia, xorg, java, 15.04

I have a REALLY odd hang that I just cant figure out.

When I start intellij (using java7/java8) my terminal will accept input for a few minutes. Then it'll stop accepting any input. vmstat shows the system is roughly 10% idle, the remaining %'s being in user and system. If I switch over to tty1 the system is completely responsive. killall -9 java solves the problem and xorg wakes up again.

It just feels REALLY REALLY weird to me that I can write in a few commands in a terminal before it stops completely. System load just keeps going up at that point forever until I switch to tty1 and it goes down again.

Any hints on how to debug this? (x64, i7, 32gb ram, nvidia native driver)

Comment: I'm guessing it's the 3-4% in system thats causing this, but how can I figure out what in system it's doing. And why that keeps system load going up forever?

Comment: iowait is non existant (and on an ssd)

Comment: tried using # sar -I XALL  2 100000 | egrep -v '0,00$' to track irq usage, and it doesn't seem to be particularly high either. I also tried kernel 4.x and no change :/

Comment: same thing happens when starting it remotely through ssh with X forwarding. So it's not something it's doing with the gui that's causing it. Switching to tty1 and the load keeps going up, going to do a kernel bug report and see if that can help solve it.

Comment: Did you get any further with this issue? I have something extremely similar happening.

Comment: The issue was actually related to suspend2ram. I strongly suspect some bios bug causing io to hang under some circumstances. A hard reboot solves the problem (soft reboot does not!)